# Problems debugging Django `collectstatic` in a cloudControl deployment

Tags: python, django, cloudcontrol

I have a Django application deployed to cloudControl. Configuration is standard and the push/deploy happens without (apparent) errors.

But the [collectstatic step](https://github.com/cloudControl/buildpack-python/blob/master/bin/steps/collectstatic) is not being executed: it fails silently (I see no `-----> Collecting static files` message). After the deploy, the static folder for the application is empty, so you get 500 Server Errors continually.

**I can solve it changing the `Procfile`, but it is not consistent either:**

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; gunicorn app.wsgi:application --config gunicorn_cnf.py --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT:-5000}`
```

---

collectstatic works as it should locally, and if I run `cctrlapp app/deployment run "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"` no errors are shown either:

> 669 static files copied to '/srv/www/staticfiles/static', 669 post-processed.

But `/srv/www/staticfiles/static` is empty.

---

How can I know why collectstatic is not being executed in the push phase?

Comment: FYI: the `staticfiles/static` folder is included in the repo, with a dummy file. The deployment has the folder created as expected... with no dummy file (a `.gitignore`).

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the run-time environment with `run bash` for potential path problems that resulted in the buildpack output and the actual filesystem structure to differ? Unlikely, but just to rule that out, the output directory is not by any chance included in a `.cctrlignore` file? https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/platform-documentation#image-building

Comment: No, no `.cctrlignore` file is used. If I `run bash` I can see the the static files folder where it should be (`/srv/www/staticfiles/static`) but it is empty. If I `run "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"` a success message is shown, but files are not added either (I guess because workers are different). The only way of having the files is to prepend the command to the `Procfile`, but then I get some inconsistencies (not all statics are collected: for example for the django-pagedown package, that relies on a git module).

Comment: @pst View answer with my conclusions. Any other cleaner way of checking if we are in the push phase?

Comment: There is a environment variable `BUILDPACK_RUNNING` set while the buildpack is running during push. Impressive work, debugging this issue.

Comment: @pst Thanks! I have edited my answer adding a reference to `BUILDPACK_RUNNING`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to debug the problem, using a [custom python buildpack](https://github.com/eillarra/buildpack-python), so here is the answer for further reference.

The problem was in the `settings.py` file. The first thing I do in this file is to check if we are in a cloudControl environment or in a local environment. I do it looking for the `CRED_FILE` environment variable (not so different of [what is suggested](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/guides/python/django)): if no variable is found, I load a local JSON file that mimics that credentials variable for development:

```py
try:
    cred_file = os.environ['CRED_FILE']
    DEBUG = False

except KeyError:
    cred_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'creds.json')
    DEBUG = True
```

Once I know the environment, I can have different `INSTALLED_APPS` (`requirements.txt` files are slightly different in production and development, too) or change some settings.

**Now the bad news: in the push phase there is no `CRED_FILE` available.**

So I was trying to load apps that were not installed (because they were only in the development requirements file, like `coverage` or `django-debug-toolbar`) or use credentials that were not set (`creds.json` is, of course, not uploaded to the repository: only a TXT with dummy values is uploaded as a reference). That's why `collectstatic` was failing silently in the push phase.

Here is my solution (it will work as long as you have a dummy credentials file in your repo):

```py
try:
    cred_file = os.environ['CRED_FILE']
    DEBUG = False

except KeyError:
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'creds.json')):
        cred_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'creds.json')
        DEBUG = True
    else:
        cred_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'creds.json.txt')
        DEBUG = False
```

Credentials are not used by `collectstatic`, so you can have anything in the `creds.json.txt` file. Not very clean, but it works as expected now.

---

**EDIT**

As pointed by @pst in a comment there is an environment variable to know if the buildpack is running, so we could use that one too to load the desired credentials and set `DEBUG`.

```py
if 'CRED_FILE' in os.environ:
    cred_file = os.environ['CRED_FILE']
    DEBUG = False

elif 'BUILDPACK_RUNNING' in os.environ:
    cred_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'creds.json.txt') 
    DEBUG = False

else:
    cred_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'creds.json')
    DEBUG = True
```

Comment: Do you still need the fake creds.json.txt?

Comment: The way my settings are configured yes. But it is not a problem because the dummy file is always in the repo as a reference for developers (they need to fill in the right settings for local development and rename it).

Comment: @pst I could remove dummy file if I then use `dict.get('key', 'default_cred')` when loading the credentials. What I do need if I use this way is to check if `cred_file`is defined using a `except NameError` and set a couple of empty dictionaries...